# Transistor as switch between similar voltages

Tags: transistors, switches, relay, xbee, boost

I want to use an XBee to relay data coming from a serial device. The XBee will be sleeping most of the time; waking at regular intervals, powering on the serial device, relaying the serial signals, then going back to sleep (thus powering off the serial device).

The XBee runs at 3.3V and the serial device runs at 3.6V. I plan to use a voltage divider to shift the logic levels (allowing for up to 3.9V coming from the serial device - when it is in a different mode, it can accept up to 3.9V on this pin and I'd rather be safe than sorry). The XBee isn't capable of powering the serial device on its own, so I plan to use a transistor as a relay. My questions are...

1. Is this the correct approach?
2. I'm lacking confidence in my ability to select the proper transistor and base resistor, can someone give me a hand?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Oakq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Serial Device**
Supply Voltage: 3.6V to 15V
Current Draw: 0.5mA to 30mA
Communications: 0-3.6V active-high, 1200bps, 1 start, 8 data, no parity, 1 stop bit.

**Xbee**
Supply Voltage: 2.1V to 3.6V
Output Voltage: 0.82*VCC (1.722V to 2.952V)
Output Current: 16mA
Input-Low Max: 0.2*VCC (0.42V to 0.72V)
Input-High Min: 0.8*VCC (1.68V to 2.88V)
Input Leakage Current: 0.5uA (Max)

Answer (score 1):

1. The transistor does not seem to be connected correctly. (The collector is forward biased). Have you mistakenly replaced an NPN transistor by a PNP version?
2. You seem to be switching the the Booster, and not the serial module directly. So, check the response time of the DC booster. It must not take long to reach the 5V equilibrium after subsequent switch ON/OFF.
3. Assuming you have replaced the PNP by an NPN, since the ground to the serial module is connected through the "switch", the drop across the switch will raise the voltage of the ground by typically 100mV to 300mV, depending on the type of transistor used, hence your ground is no more at zero. To make up for this, the high-signal to the module should be raised by 100mV to 300mV.

Comment: You're right, that should be an NPN. I forgot to change it back after playing around with a PNP configuration.

I haven't decided on a boost solution yet, but I figured that would be relatively trivial. I put it after the "switch" in an effort to maximize battery life.

Do you think it would make more sense to go with a PNP solution instead of an NPN? Can you give me an example of a transistor you would recommend? Are you saying I should raise the entirety of the data signal by a fixed 100-300mV, or will changing R1 to 10k suffice? Thanks a bunch, this stuff is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep things simple and My suggestion would be to use a 6-9V battery bank and then use an adjustable linear regulator to generate 3.6V. This voltage is compatible with both devices. A suitable linear regulator would be the [LM317](http://www.ti.com/product/lm317). There is an application note [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf).

Comment: Unfortunately, for this particular use case, 2x AAs are pretty much the only option. A 2x AA holder and an XBee sit nicely on top of the serial device. The total package needs to fit in a particular space, needs to last 6 months to a year on a set of batteries, and the batteries need to be end-user replaceable (ie: not LiPo packs).
Thanks for the suggestion though!